# I create a RecyclerView in Fragment but while reloading data RecyclerView does not maintains state.

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

//I have created RecycleView in Fragment as follows:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_shop, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        stackView = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.stack_view);
        firstStack = (CustomImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.firstStack);
        secondStack = (CustomImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.secondStack);
        thirdStack = (CustomImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thirdStack);
        stackTopGap = view.findViewById(R.id.view);
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                firstStack.getLayoutParams().width = stackView.getWidth() - 40;
                secondStack.getLayoutParams().width = stackView.getWidth() - 80;
                thirdStack.getLayoutParams().width = stackView.getWidth() - 120;
                width = thirdStack.getLayoutParams().width;
                recyclerView.getLayoutParams().height = recyclerView.getHeight() - (firstStack.getHeight() + stackTopGap.getHeight());
                stackView.getLayoutParams().height = firstStack.getHeight();
            }
        });
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()) {
            @Override
            public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position) {
                // A good idea would be to create this instance in some initialization method, and just set the target position in this method.
                LinearSmoothScroller smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(getContext()) {
                    @Override
                    public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
                        //int yDelta = calculateCurrentDistanceToPosition(targetPosition);
                        return new PointF(0, 200);
                    }

                    // This is the important method. This code will return the amount of time it takes to scroll 1 pixel.
                    // This code will request X milliseconds for every Y DP units.
                    @Override
                    protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
                        return 7 / TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 7, displayMetrics);
                    }

                };
                smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
                startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(final RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                final int positionView = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastVisibleItemPosition();

                if (dy > 0) {
                    if (positionView >= 2) {
                        final View view = recyclerView.getChildAt(2);
                        if (view != null && recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == positionView) {
                            TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 200, 0);
                            translateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                                    if (counter == 0) {
                                        if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 4 >= positionView) {
                                            createStackImageView();
                                        }
                                        if (stackView.getChildAt(1) != null) {
                                            //stackView.getChildAt(1).setScaleX(1.5f);
                                        }
                                        counter++;
                                    }
                                    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(positionView);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                                    view.clearAnimation();
                                    stackView.requestLayout();
                                    stackView.removeView(stackView.getChildAt(1));
                                    stackView.invalidate();
                                    try {
                                        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
                                            Glide.with(getActivity())
                                                    .load(JSONUrl.IMAGE_BASE_URL + imageList.get(positionView + i))
                                                    .into((ImageView) stackView.getChildAt(i));
                                        }
                                    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException | NullPointerException | IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                                        ex.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    counter = 0;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                                }
                            });
                            translateAnimation.setDuration(150);
                            view.setAnimation(translateAnimation);
                        }
                    }
                    for (int i = stackView.getChildCount() - 1; i >= 2; i--) {
                        ResizeAnimation resizeAnimation = new ResizeAnimation(stackView.getChildAt(i));
                        resizeAnimation.setHeights(stackView.getChildAt(i).getHeight(), stackView.getChildAt(i - 1).getHeight());
                        resizeAnimation.setWidths(stackView.getChildAt(i).getWidth(), stackView.getChildAt(i - 1).getWidth());
                        resizeAnimation.setDuration(200);
                        stackView.getChildAt(i).startAnimation(resizeAnimation);
                    }
                } else if (dy < 0) {
                    final int position = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                    if (position == imageList.size() - 1) {
                        stackView.removeView(firstStack);
                        stackView.addView(firstStack);
                        stackView.invalidate();
                        stackView.requestLayout();
                        stackView.getChildAt(1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Glide.with(getActivity())
                                .load(JSONUrl.IMAGE_BASE_URL + imageList.get(imageList.size() - 1))
                                .into((ImageView) stackView.getChildAt(1));
                    } else if (position == imageList.size() - 2) {
                        stackView.removeView(secondStack);
                        stackView.addView(secondStack);
                        secondStack.getLayoutParams().height = firstStack.getHeight() - 20;
                        secondStack.getLayoutParams().width = firstStack.getWidth() - 40;
                        stackView.invalidate();
                        stackView.requestLayout();
                        stackView.getChildAt(2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Glide.with(getActivity())
                                .load(JSONUrl.IMAGE_BASE_URL + imageList.get(imageList.size() - 2))
                                .into((ImageView) stackView.getChildAt(2));
                    } else if (position == imageList.size() - 3) {
                        stackView.removeView(thirdStack);
                        stackView.addView(thirdStack);
                        thirdStack.getLayoutParams().height = secondStack.getHeight() - 20;
                        thirdStack.getLayoutParams().width = secondStack.getWidth() - 40;
                        stackView.invalidate();
                        stackView.requestLayout();
                        stackView.getChildAt(3).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Glide.with(getActivity())
                                .load(JSONUrl.IMAGE_BASE_URL + imageList.get(imageList.size() - 3))
                                .into((ImageView) stackView.getChildAt(3));
                    } else {
                        stackView.removeView(firstStack);
                        stackView.addView(firstStack);
                        stackView.invalidate();
                        stackView.requestLayout();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

//In validateToken method data is taken from the json and set to adapter as follows.

```
private void validateToken() {
        final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        if (new ConnectionManager(getActivity()).isConnectedToInternet()) {
            final SweetAlertDialog pDialog = new AlertDIalogMessage().showProgressDialog(getActivity(), "Loading...");
            if (sharedPreferences.getString(SharedPrefrenceInfo.IS_TOKEN_VALID, "token_invalid").equals("token_invalid")) {
                Utils.setTokenInfo(getActivity(), pDialog, new AccessTokenInfoHolder() {
                    @Override
                    public void setAcessTokenInfo(String accessToken, String expires_in, String token_type) {
                        Log.e("Access Token", accessToken);
                        new ShopFragmentJson(getActivity()).getShopPageContent(pDialog, sharedPreferences.getString(SharedPrefrenceInfo.TOKEN_TYPE, "") + " " + sharedPreferences.getString(SharedPrefrenceInfo.IS_TOKEN_VALID, ""), new ShopPageContentHolder() {
                            @Override
                            public void setErrorShopPageContent(String statusCode, String statusText) {
                                //do nothing here since the  case unauthorized will not arrive for the first time
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void setSuccessShopPageContent(String success, String data) {
                                if (success.equals("true")) {
                                    shoppageInfoList = getShopPageContent(data);
                                    //set the adapter after loading data from url
                                    final NewShopFragmentAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new NewShopFragmentAdapter(getActivity(), recyclerView.getHeight(), shoppageInfoList);
                                    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
                                    pDialog.dismiss();
                                } else {
                                    pDialog.dismiss();
                                    new AlertDIalogMessage().showErrorDialog(getActivity(), data);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                new ShopFragmentJson(getActivity()).getShopPageContent(pDialog, sharedPreferences.getString(SharedPrefrenceInfo.TOKEN_TYPE, "") + " " + sharedPreferences.getString(SharedPrefrenceInfo.IS_TOKEN_VALID, ""), new ShopPageContentHolder() {
                    @Override
                    public void setErrorShopPageContent(String statusCode, String statusText) {
                        //this method is invoked when unauthorized response come from server
                        Utils.setTokenInfo(getActivity(), pDialog, new AccessTokenInfoHolder() {
                            @Override
                            public void setAcessTokenInfo(String accessToken, String expires_in, String token_type) {
                                new ShopFragmentJson(getActivity()).getShopPageContent(pDialog, sharedPreferences.getString(SharedPrefrenceInfo.TOKEN_TYPE, "") + " " + sharedPreferences.getString(SharedPrefrenceInfo.IS_TOKEN_VALID, ""), new ShopPageContentHolder() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void setErrorShopPageContent(String statusCode, String statusText) {
                                        //do nothing here since the  case unauthorized will not arrive for the first time
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void setSuccessShopPageContent(String success, String data) {
                                        if (success.equals("true")) {
                                            List<ShoppageInfo> shoppageInfoList = getShopPageContent(data);
                                            final NewShopFragmentAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new NewShopFragmentAdapter(getActivity(), recyclerView.getHeight(), shoppageInfoList);
                                            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
                                            pDialog.dismiss();
                                        } else {
                                            pDialog.dismiss();
                                            new AlertDIalogMessage().showErrorDialog(getActivity(), data);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void setSuccessShopPageContent(String success, String data) {
                        if (success.equals("true")) {
                            List<ShoppageInfo> shoppageInfoList = getShopPageContent(data);
                            //set the adapter after loading data from url
                            final NewShopFragmentAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new NewShopFragmentAdapter(getActivity(), recyclerView.getHeight(), shoppageInfoList);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                        } else {
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                            new AlertDIalogMessage().showErrorDialog(getActivity(), data);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            new SweetAlertDialog(getActivity(), SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE)
                    .setTitleText("Oops...")
                    .setContentText("No internet connection!")
                    .show();
        }
    }
```

No in  onResume method i called validate token as follows:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        validateToken();
    }
```

//Now when I call some activity from this fragment and come back with back pressed validate method is called and RecyclerView adapter is reloaded. Now what I want is to maintain the state of RecyclerView such that when I came back from activity RecyclerView stays in the scroll position from when activity is called. But problem for me is it always come from the start. I also see some Stack Overflow post and they suggest me to use Parceable but i don't  get any benefit. Is is doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Can try this.
You need to maintain an identifier for each row. Then save the first visible row's identifier before you go to the activity. Then when you come back you select that particular row again.